# Using service in template

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular6

I have this code in a template:

```
<li *ngFor="let ship of shipService.sideNavigationShips">
    {{ship.name}}
</li>
```

And something like this in my service (service is injected in component which calls `service.loadSideNavigationShips()` on `init`):

```
sideNavigationShips: ShipDto[];

async loadSideNavigationShips() {
    this.sideNavigationShips = (await this.search()).data.result;
}

async createShip(ship: ShipDto) {

    await this.create(ship);
    this.loadSideNavigationShips();
}
```

This way when some other component calls `createShip()`, the `shipService.sideNavigationShips` in template will be automatically updated.

But I guess something might be wrong with this approach, as I have never seen  service being directly used in a template. I would like to know if I am missing something and if there are any downsides to this.

Comment: Indeed, you should call the service in the component, save the result in a variable, and use that one instead.

Comment: I suppose so, but I needed to know why :) If I do so, I lose the auto update of sideNavigationShips list in a template.

Comment: Hmm, auto-update? How do you get it? If you can get it direclty, why shouldn't it work through the controller?

Comment: Calling a service in the template is poor form. It will work, but your business logic should be in the component. Remember that the more the template has to do, the higher the rendering cost. If you need to use a get/set for your update. Even better use an rxjs Subject or BehaviorSubject instead of async.